# Trying to center 3 div blocks alongside each other with gaps between, they are aligned next to each another horizontally

Tags: html, css

```
#block1 {
    background-color: blue;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

#block1 p {
            color: white;
}

#block2 {
        background-color: blue;
        font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
        width: 25%;
        padding: 4px;
        border-radius: 1em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        float: left;
        display: block;
}

#block2 p {
            color: white;
}

#block3 {
    background-color: blue;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

#block3 p {
        color: white;
}
```

As you can see I've set up the three blocks to align next to each other but I'm just struggling to centre them with spaces between. 
I've set it so that the blocks all float alongside each other but they simply go to the left as designated with the float left, is there a way I can make them centred?

Comment: Don't use `float`, use `display:inline-block` and on the parent container add `text-align:center` - http://jsfiddle.net/fku0h4b1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use float, use `display:inline-block` and on the parent container add `text-align:center`

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```